# Excel: how to move "questions" into columns and "answers" to rows when the raw data is all in rows?

Tags: excel

Hi I'm a starter in excel and got a table that I need to tidy up. I have been searching but couldn't find a quick way to make it happen. Can anyone help please?

I have a raw data of survey like below:

Name           Question                                                            Answer
NameA       how old are you?                                       10yrs old
NameB       how old are you?                                        25yrs old
NameC       how old are you?                                        15yrs old
NameD       how old are you?                          17yrs old
NameE       how old are you?                          32yrs old
NameA       What's your favourite colour?         Green
NameB       What's your favourite colour?         Purple
NameC       What's your favourite colour?         Red
NameD       What's your favourite colour?         White
NameE       What's your favourite colour?         Black

How can I make it to:

Name        How old are you?    What's your favourite colour?

NameA      10yrs old                Green

NameB      25yrs old                Purple

NameC      15yrs old                Red

NameD      17yrs old                White

NameE      32yrs old                Black

Comment: How far have you gotten?  What have you tried?  What were the results?  Are you looking for a worksheet function or a macro solution?  Where do you want to show the results?  Can you generate the lists of Names and Questions (row and column labels)?

Comment: Sorry I'm only a basic user. I can only do pivot table and some simple formula like vlookup, if, and etc. I tried to use pivot table but it can only count the value rather than show the value. It'll be great to show the result in another sheet. I don't really get your last question "Can you generate the lists of Names and Questions (row and column labels)?" Ron (Thanks for your comment)

Comment: Just means do you need formulas or a method to produce the row and column labels that you show in your results table, or can you enter them manually?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you source table starts in cell A1 and goes down maybe to cell C12 and you put all your names in a list starting in F2 and the questions in the first row starting in column G1. Then you can put the following formula in G2:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$12,
   (SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=$F2)*($B$2:$B$12=G$1)*ROW($C$2:$C$12)))-1)
```

and drag it down and it will give the result, that you wished.